# jQuery: Move element by relative value

Tags: jquery, css-position, element, move

(Meaning an elements left-value):
What's the easiest way to move an element - e.g. 10px to the left (from its current position)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be that jQuery is overkill and setting margin-left: -10px will do the trick.

You can get an element's offset() relative to the document: http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset

That'd give you the left,top,etc.

Then you might have to position the element using the css like so.

```
 subMenu.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 5000,
            left: left,
            top: top
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick example using jQuery:

```
$("#el").css({
    left: $("#el").position().left - 10 + "px"
});
```

Note: the element that you want to move must either be positioned absolutely or relatively.

Comment: or $("#el").css('left', '-=10px')

Comment: This won't work if this command is directly after a JQuery UI element.position({...}) call, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your element has the id 'myElement':

```
$('#myElement').css(
{
  'position': 'relative',
  'left': '-10px'
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As of 1.6 you can use relative values in `css()` so you could use this:

```
$('#myElement).css( "left", "+=15" );
```

As long as the element already has a defined value for `left` and is absolutely positioned.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers are true jQuery-style solutions, i'll resurrect this old issue.

This solution can move ALL of the selected elements by a relative value:

```
$('.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).css({ left: $(this).position().left - 10 });
});
```