# jQuery, How to move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pointers, slide

I have a triangle pointer, which should move to certain position (let's say 50px to the right), when button is clicked. I am a jQuery newbie - how can this be done using jQuery?

The HTML code is following:

```
<div class="pointerholder">
   <div class="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pointerholder {
   position: relative;
   width: 600px;
   margin: auto;
}

.pointer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 0 10px 13px 10px;
   border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
   line-height: 0px;
   _border-color: #000000 #000000 #f4f5f5 #000000;
   _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');  
}
```

Can sliding animation achieved as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: move element by relative value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806246/jquery-move-element-by-relative-value)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/OGiwEwI/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        $('.pointerholder').animate({
            'left': '+=50px'
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6X79n/2)

Answer (score 0):

Be simple! :)

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('pointer').css('margin-left', '10px');
}
```

Or add any other value to the margin so that it moves 10 px far. You will require to either remove the `position: absolute;` or you can use this:

```
$('pointer').css('left', '10'); // 10px margin from left..to the right
```

To achieve that, you can use this:

```
.animate();
```

Go to the links below to learn more about them, since you want to learn them for now! :)

#### Reference

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
 $('.pointer').animate({
        left: +600
    },1500)
```